# How to change the color of focused and selected rows in DevExpress TcxGrid using different colors?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I want to change the color of **selected records (marked check boxes)** and **focused record** in a TcxGrid by different colors.

Comment: Questions that are written to be self-answered are still required to meet the same quality standards as any other question here. You may want to review [ask].

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for taking time to review the post, I reviewed my question according to "How to Ask" post, and made changes in Title. I think the question itself meets the quality standards, but if you don't think so I'll be happy to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the code below:

```
procedure TMyForm.cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if AViewInfo.GridRecord.Focused then
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clBlue;

  if AViewInfo.GridRecord.Selected then
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
end;
```

if you want to change the color of just cell instead of the whole row, you can do it by removing **.GridRecord** expression after **AviewInfo**.